# Issue saving in core data in multithreaded application

Tags: ios, ios5, core-data, ios4, core-data-migration

I am having a problem in saving the data in Core Data while im multithreaded application. The scenario is the following:

I have some http requests which runs in background threads us `NSOperation`. When the data arrives which is in JSON I tried to save those data in Core Data.
I have created the separate `NSManagedObjectContext` for each thread now when I try to save the data it never saves properly. Sometime half data is saved sometime none.

Any guesses why this is hapaneing

```
+ (void) initialize {
    contextfactory = [[ThreadedContext alloc] init];
}

- (id) init {
    if((self = [super init])) {
    }
    [self setupObjectModel];
    [self setupStoreCoordinator];
    return self;
}

- (void) setupObjectModel {
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
}    

- (NSString*) sharedDocumentsPath {
    static NSString *SharedDocumentsPath = nil;
    if (SharedDocumentsPath)
        return SharedDocumentsPath;

    // Compose a path to the <Library>/Database directory
    NSString *libraryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    return  [[libraryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database"] retain];

}

- (NSURL *) storeUrl {

    NSString * const kCoreDataSQLiteName = @"XPPS.sqlite";
    // Get the paths to the SQLite file
    NSString *storePath = [[self sharedDocumentsPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:kCoreDataSQLiteName];
    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:storePath];
}

- (void) setupStoreCoordinator {
    NSError *error = nil;
    if(!_persistentStoreCoordinator)
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel: _managedObjectModel];
    [_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL: [self storeUrl] options:nil error:&error];
    if(error) NSLog(@"%@", error);
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *) createObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *output = [[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init] autorelease];
    [output setPersistentStoreCoordinator:_persistentStoreCoordinator];
    return output;
}

+ (NSManagedObjectContext *) buildContext {
    return [contextfactory createObjectContext];
}

+ (void) createStoreCoordinator {
    [contextfactory setupStoreCoordinator];
}

+ (NSString *) storePath {
    return [[contextfactory storeUrl] path];
}
```

This is the code for getting the managed context for the each thread. It is derived from `NSObject` and not `NSOperation`. Any guess how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you see [this apple example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ThreadedCoreData/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010723)?

Your code seems good but it is only one important think to create NSManageObject for every background thread. This example can show you how can you use the  `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` and save your data on a safe way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save on the main thread. Just make a `NSNotification` and notify the main thread of the new data and save there. No need for multiple contexts.

Comment: can you give me a example how i can do this & also do this work as i have multiple threads trying to save data at same time.

Comment: You can read up on notifications [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003701). I think the concurrent threads would not matter, because the saves in the main thread would still be sequential.

Comment: its not saving the data. If i set the NSOperation setMaxConcurrentOperationCount = 1 than it works fine but if i increase the count to 2,3 or 4 it never works..

Comment: Did you try with notifications? I do it all the time... Another variation is to have singletons doing the download and make your main view the delegate...